# Overriding default accessor method across different classloaders breaks polymorphism

Tags: java, inheritance, polymorphism, classloader

I come across to a strange behavior while trying to override a method with *default accessor* (ex: `void run()`).
According to Java spec, a class can use or override default members of base class if classes belongs to the same package.
Everything works correctly while all classes loaded from the same classloader.
But if I try to load a subclass from *separate* classloader then polymorphism don't work.

Here is sample:

App.java:

```
import java.net.*;
import java.lang.reflect.Method;

public class App {
    public static class Base {
        void run() {
            System.out.println("error");
        }
    }
    public static class Inside extends Base {
        @Override
        void run() {
            System.out.println("ok. inside");
        }
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        {
            Base p = (Base) Class.forName(Inside.class.getName()).newInstance();
            System.out.println(p.getClass());
            p.run();
        } {
            // path to Outside.class
            URL[] url = { new URL("file:/home/mart/workspace6/test2/bin/") };
            URLClassLoader ucl = URLClassLoader.newInstance(url);
            final Base p = (Base) ucl.loadClass("Outside").newInstance();
            System.out.println(p.getClass());
            p.run();
            // try reflection
            Method m = p.getClass().getDeclaredMethod("run");
            m.setAccessible(true);
            m.invoke(p);
        }
    }
}
```

Outside.java: should be in separate folder. otherwise classloader will be the same

```
public class Outside extends App.Base {
    @Override
    void run() {
        System.out.println("ok. outside");
    }
}
```

The output:

```
class App$Inside
ok. inside
class Outside
error
ok. outside
```

So then I call `Outside#run()` I got `Base#run()` ("error" in output). Reflections works correctly.

Whats wrong? Or is it expected behavior?
Can I go around this problem somehow?

Comment: I notice that your `Outside` class declares `run` to be public...I wonder if that is the problem. Can you try it with `Outside.run` having default access?

Comment: If `Outside#run` has default accessor when Reflections (without `setAccessible(true)`) _also_ don't work: ``Exception in thread "main" `java.lang.IllegalAccessException: Class App can not access a member of class Outside with modifiers ""`

Comment: I rewrote sample for Outside#run has default accessor

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From [Java Virtual Machine Specification](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jvms/):

> **5.3 Creation and Loading**
>   ...
>   At run time, a class or interface is
>   determined not by its name alone, but
>   by a pair: its fully qualified name
>   and its defining class loader. Each
>   such class or interface belongs to a
>   single *runtime package*. The runtime
>   package of a class or interface is
>   determined by the package name and
>   defining class loader of the class or
>   interface.
>
> ---
>
> **5.4.4 Access Control**
>   ...
>   A field or method R is *accessible* to a class
>   or interface D if and only if any of
>   the following conditions is true:
>
> - ...
> - R is either `protected` or package private (that is, neither `public` nor
>     `protected` nor `private`), and is
>     declared by a class in the same
>     runtime package as D.

Comment: Is there any way to add external class to main classloader?

Comment: @mart: Actually, you can call protected method `URLClassLoader.addURL()` via reflection (with `setAccessible(true)`), and it works as desired, but it's definitely a hack. However, you may write your own classloader where adding resources at runtime would be a legitimate behaviour, and use it to load all these classes.

Answer (score 2):

The Java Language Specification mandates that a class can only override methods that it can access. If the super class method is not accessible, it is shadowed rather than overridden.

Reflection "works" because you ask `Outside.class` for its run method. If you ask `Base.class` instead, you'll get the super implementation:

```
        Method m = Base.class.getDeclaredMethod("run");
        m.setAccessible(true);
        m.invoke(p);
```

You can verify that the method is deemed inaccessible by doing:

```
public class Outside extends Base {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        System.out.println("Outside.");
        super.run(); // throws an IllegalAccessError
    }
}
```

So, why is the method not accessible? I am not totally sure, but I suspect that just like equally named classes loaded by different class loaders result in different runtime classes, equally named packages loaded by different class loaders result in different runtime packages.

**Edit**: Actually, the reflection API says that it's the same package:

```
    Base.class.getPackage() == p.getClass().getPackage() // true
```

Comment: Thank you for answer. Your suspection seems reasonably. Maybe JVM consider the packages are different for different classloaders.

Comment: Is the way to avoid this? Maybe it is possible to add a class to the main classloader?

Answer (score 1):

I found the (hack) way to load external class in main classloader so this problem is gone.

Read a class as bytes and invoke protected [ClassLoader#defineClass](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/ClassLoader.html) method.

code:

```
URL[] url = { new URL("file:/home/mart/workspace6/test2/bin/") };
URLClassLoader ucl = URLClassLoader.newInstance(url);

InputStream is = ucl.getResourceAsStream("Outside.class");
byte[] bytes = new byte[is.available()];
is.read(bytes);
Method m = ClassLoader.class.getDeclaredMethod("defineClass", new Class[] { String.class, byte[].class, int.class, int.class });
m.setAccessible(true);
Class<Base> outsideClass = (Class<Base>) m.invoke(Base.class.getClassLoader(), "Outside", bytes, 0, bytes.length);

Base p = outsideClass.newInstance();
System.out.println(p.getClass());
p.run();
```

outputs `ok. outside` as expected.