# How do you access protected Java method in thirdparty library?

Tags: java, methods, protected

Assume that you must access a protected method of a Java object that you receive somewhere in your code. What is your solution?

I know one approach: You can employ reflection and call setAccessible(true) on the Method object.

Any other idea?

Comment: Are you working with a library that has a published API?  If so, add that info to the question; you'll get better help.

Comment: It is not the first time I encounter this issue but if you are curious: Eclipse Debug Plugin, JDILocalVariable, getStackFrame. Url: http://www.docjar.com/docs/api/org/eclipse/jdt/internal/debug/core/model/JDILocalVariable.html

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As per the [Java access modifiers](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html), besides extending the object (which you can't if you receive the object) is to access it from an object in the same package as the object you received. So your option is to **create a wrapper class in the same package** which retrieves the attribute via the protected method for you.

Answer (score 6):

You can subclass the method, create a public method that calls the protected method and returns the result.

If you can't do that (if the class is final), then setAccessible is pretty much your only way.

Comment: Consider that you receive the object. You can not cast the object, can you?

Comment: I assume you mean convert it to another type. No, you cannot convert the object type (class) to another object type at runtime. You can wrap it inside another object, but the problem with protected access still remains. Also, if your object is generated using spring or hibernate or any other framework that makes use of runtime proxying, it's not guaranteed that reflection will work either. The target proxy will not contain any methods that are not public in the proxied class.

Answer (score 4):

One other option is to create a class that extends that 3rd party class that has the protected method that you are interested in.

```
public class ThirdPartyClass
{
   protected void foo(){}
}
```

and

```
public MyClass extends ThirdPartyClass
{

     public void callFoo()
     {
           foo();
     }

}
```

Comment: Consider that you receive the object. You can not cast the object, can you?

Comment: @salman do you have access to the third party class at compile time?

Answer (score 4):

You can also extend the class, override the method, and make the overridden method be public. Then have it just call super.method().

Comment: Consider that you receive the object. You can not cast the object, can you?

Answer (score 3):

The other way is to extend the Class (if possible) and get access to the protected method via inheritance.  If you do not create the Object this is not possible, as you would need it at compile time and you would need to create the Object yourself.

A dodgy solution could be to use composition.  So you create a class in the same package e.g. OtherObjectWrapper.  As it's in the same package you could call the Object's protected method through a public API you expose.  This is not recommended though, as you don't own the package which you are adding a Class too and you can make your code very brittle e.g.

```
package com.foo;

public class OtherObjectWrapper {
   private com.foo.OtherObject wrappedObject;

   public OtherObjectWrapper(com.foo.OtherObject wrappedObject) {
     this.wrappedObject = wrappedObject;
   }

   public void callTheProtectedMethod() {
     wrappedObject.callTheProtectedMethod();
   }
}
```

Consider what the the API designer thinking when they marked the method as protected?  Maybe they didn't have a clue what they were doing and it should be public, or worse still, it should be package private or private outright.  Or maybe they did and they determined only code in the same package or through inheritance should have access to the protected method.  If it's protected it may well be for a reason, so be wary as you may tie your codes behaviour to behaviours which may change and break your code.  Also look at who owns the third party Object and whether there is a better API for accessing the protected method's functionality.

Comment: Consider that you receive the object. You can not cast the object, can you?

Answer (score 2):

If you can put the calling class in the same package you will have access to the method.
This and inheriting from that class are the only non-reflective ways to access a protected method.

Comment: Note that the calling class should be loaded by the same classloader as the third-party class, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4060842

Answer (score 2):

As already said, subclassing is normally the standard way to access that method.
Other approaches (wrapper in same package, reflection) should generally not used, since if you can't extend the class (due to being final) there often are good reasons accessing that method is made hard.

If the library is of any decent quality you definitely shouldn't have to use any other means besides subclassing to access a protected method or not access that method at all.

Answer (score 0):

If a class is not final, you can use an anonymous class to call its protected method:

```
new ClassWithProtectedMethod() {
    @Override
    protected void method() {
        super.method();
    }
}.method();
```

Note, making `method()` public is unnecessary (since the new anonymous class is in the same package).