# Java: accessing protected fields from inner class

Tags: java, classloader, inner-classes, protected, access-modifiers

Recently I've faced a problem getting a runtime error `java.lang.IllegalAccessError` when trying to access from inner class a protected field declared in outer's parent class that was loaded by a different class loader. Briefly:

1. Class `Parent` has protected field `p`.
2. Class `Outer` extends `Parent`.
3. Class `Inner` is an inner class defined in class `Outer`.
4. Inside `Inner` class there's a code: `Outer.this.p`.
5. All classes are declared in the same package.

Normally it's compiled and runs fine until `Parent` and `Outer` class are loaded by different class loaders. In this case we get `java.lang.IllegalAccessError` when trying to access `Outer.this.p` from `Inner`.
I found an old bug report (which appeared to be a feature) describing this behavior:

https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=6258289

But resolution sounds contradictive to me:

> The key is that in the failing case the inner class isn't in the same
> package (and isn't a subclass of) ConcreteCommand/AbstractCommand.
> This is simply a violation of the Java specification for protected
> classes.

It sounds correct. But if we declare `Parent` and `Outer` classes in different packages but load with the single class loader (simply create sample console app without any jar loadings) we don't get any errors. So technically it's a violation of Java spec for protected classes but since we use an inner class it works.

So we have different behavior for two cases of "different packages".

1. Declared in different packages, loaded by single class loader - OK.
2. Declared in single package, loaded by different class loaders - NOT OK.

Could someone give a clear explanation of how inner class gets access to parent's fields and why it works differently for two cases?

Comment: how are you reproducing the scenario of class getting loaded by different classloaders?

Answer (score 1):

- Same class loader it seems to be working
- Did I get the question right?
- Do you have any unit test case to reproduce your issue?

**Parent Class**

```java
package p1;

public class Parent {
    
    protected String p = "Value from Parent";
    
    public void test() {
        System.out.println(p);
    }

}
```

**Outer Class**

```java
package p1;

public class Outer extends Parent {

    class Inner {
        public void test() {
            Outer.this.p = "Value set from Inner";
            System.out.println(Outer.this.p);
        }
    }

    public void test() {
        new Inner().test();
    }
}
```

**Main Class**

```java
package p1;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Parent p = new Parent();
        p.test();
        p = new Outer();
        p.test();
    }
}
```

**Output**

```java
Value from Parent
Value set from Inner
```

Answer (score 0):

> Declared in different packages, loaded by single class loader - OK

'protected' access is considerate about parent-child relation among classes and allows child classes to access 'protected' members of parent even if they are in different packages. So, I think this is as expected.

> Declared in single package, loaded by different class loaders - NOT OK

This has to do with runtime packages. Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10465646/cant-access-protected-member-of-superclass-from-same-package-in-different-jar).
Now we know that Parent is in different runtime package than Outer and Inner due to being loaded via two different class loaders. At the same time, we also have to remember that Outer is 'child' of Parent but Inner is not. Inner doesn't have an 'Is-a' relation with Parent.

Putting it all together :
Since Parent is in a different runtime package, Inner is not able to access Parent's 'protected' members as Inner is not a child of Parent.

Comment: This is absolutely clear to me. The question here is: whey then Inner class has access to protected fields of Parent of Outer class when they are loaded by a single class loader despite being declared in different packages? Inner is still not in "Is-a" relation with Parent.